# User friendly radio buttons click detection

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm making a form with radio button among others, where an update function is called whenever the user change anything.

However I'm having a problem combining this with user friendly radio buttons, where I want a button zone around both text and the button to make it easier to click.

I'm having trouble with detecting the click on both the zone, the text and the button at the same time. - So far I've only managed it by comparing the `MouseEvent.target` with a list of `id`'s (which I have to give to every single element), which just sounds wrong in my head.

```
<div class="buttonZone">
    <input type="radio" id="choice1" />
    <label for="choice1">Choice 1</label>
</div>
<div class="buttonZone">
    <input type="radio" id="choice2" />
    <label for="choice2">Choice 2</label>
</div>
```

Any ideas would be very appreciated.

Comment: With your current structure both bottom or text will trigger a check. However, you also need to give the input a name, so the browser know to choose one or the other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can wrap the input and label text in a `label` tag (versus having them be separate elements linked using the `for` attribute) and the whole area will trigger the input.

```css
.buttonZone {
  background: #eee;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  padding: 2em;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<label class="buttonZone">
    <input type="radio" id="choice1" />
    <span>Choice 1</span>
</label>
<label class="buttonZone">
    <input type="radio" id="choice2" />
    <span>Choice 2</span>
</label>
```

Comment: I'm aware of that. However when I retrieve the mouse target in JavaScript, this doesn't seem to work, as it still treats the input and span elements as separate elements and thereby not trigger the update function. - And I'm not sure how to work around that.

Comment: @Tc_ you need to be more specific. Seems fine to me http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jBEyJy

Comment: I can see that. Now I'm kinda intrigued to know what I did wrong. - But thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried giving values to the buttons?

```
<div class="buttonZone">
     <input type="radio" id="choice1" value="Choice 1" />
</div>
<div class="buttonZone">
     <input type="radio" id="choice2" value="Choice 2" />
</div>
```